# creating many divs with content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, class, for-loop

I'm trying to learn javascript and would like create something like the code below using javascript whereas I then can change the number of images/divs that's gonna be created on the page easily.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img1low.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img2low.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img3low.JPG">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="images/img4low.JPG">
        </div>
    </div>
```

edit: I started on something like this to try creating divs..

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.className = "column";
    document.getElementById("temp").appendChild(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s plenty of ways to add HTML using JavaScript.

You could just insert a HTML string using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="column">' +
                          '<img src="images/img1low.JPG">…</div></div>';
```

Another way is to use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) first and then use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
var row = document.createElement('div');
row.className = 'column';
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'images/img1low.JPG';
row.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(row);
```

Of course, there are both upsides and downsides to each possibility. Parsing HTML string is super fast, but may be considered not that clean. Creating and appending lots of elements might get exhausting. If that happens, you can relax using [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) elements and the [`importNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) method:

```
<template id="div-column-template">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</template>

document.body.appendChild(
    document.importNode(
        document.getElementById('div-column-template').content,true)
); // don’t forget to set the src attribute first
```

Comment: Thank you @dakab I'll try this

Comment: @magicjohan: You are very welcome. Just remember there are various ways and all may come in handy. Be sure to check out both ancient and cutting-edge methods to create repeating elements.